# OpenGL ES 2.0 sharing esContext in C++

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es, embedded

I am going through a seemingly popular book titled "ES 2.0 Programming Guide." In this book, there is sample code for a simple ES 2.0 program for drawing a triangle. Here is a snippet of the program that is giving me compile issues:

```
int Init ( ESContext *esContext )
{
   UserData *userData = esContext->userData;
    //etc... rest of the function
}
```

When I try to compile, line 3 here gives an error C2440: cannot convert void * to UserData *

There are a couple errors later in the program that i suspect may be related:

```
   // Load the vertex/fragment shaders
   vertexShader = LoadShader ( GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vShaderStr );
   fragmentShader = LoadShader ( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fShaderStr );
```

here, the compiler has problems with vShaderStr and fShaderStr: GLbyte * is incompatible with param of type const char *

What is going wrong with the conversions? why is esContext->userData giving problems?

The sample code is presented in C. I am attempting to compile in C++, but I don't see how exactly this is affecting it, if it is.

Can anyone give me some guidance? Is there a C component here that is not supported by C++? Is there some kind of C++ component that is creating the error?

Thanks for any help! The full sample code is viewable [here](http://opengles-book-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Windows/Chapter_2/Hello_Triangle/Hello_Triangle.c)

Comment: You have an conversion' : cannot convert from 'type1' to 'type2'. Have a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

One of the major incompatibilities between C and C++ is in the are of type conversions.

In particular, in C, you can freely convert a `void*` to any other pointer type without the need for a cast. This freedom does not exist in C++: There you need a cast to convert a `void*` to anything else.

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much. That will almost definitely solve the problem. Thanks again!